# PowerShell Documentation for RegEx language

Tags: regex, powershell

Where in the PowerShell docs does it talk about using the special variables $1, $2, etc. to represent captures in a `-replace` regex?

```
'asdf' -replace '(a)(\w{3})', '$2$1';

# Result: sdfa
```

It doesn't seem to appear in `about_Comparison_Operators`, where I'd expect it to, along with the `-replace` operator. I also looked in `about_Regular_Expressions`, and it doesn't appear in there.

I did find an example at this blog post, but can't seem to locate anything in the official docs.

http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com/2009/06/regular-expressions-in-powershell.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell is based on the .Net framework, so Powershell uses the same regex-"engine". For documentation on the regex language .Net uses, check out:

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

`$(number)` are characters used for `Substitutions`

Btw, if you had read the whole `Get-help about_Regular_Expressions` (especially the last sentences), you would have seen:

> For more information, see the "Regular Expression Language Elements"
>   topic in the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) library at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=133231.

Comment: I found an even more relevant document here, from the link you provided: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Nice =) I tried to keep it general so the question/answer wouldn't be too localized.